# Ruby on Rails - showing posts of signed in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just starting out with Rails and I got stuck with displaying properties that only belongs to signed in user.

I have a user, post model with the following associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and on post controller I'm trying to access current user's posts with session helper method called `current_user` but it complains that `posts` is undefined

```
def index
  @posts = current_user.posts
end
```

This is the helper method

```
def current_user
    remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end
```

Can someone please shed some light on it?

**Error Message**
NoMethodError in PostsController#index
undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass

Comment: may be your current_user is nil.

Comment: make sure you have included current_user helper method in your controller.

Comment: how do I make sure help method can be referenced in controller?

Comment: Use - include YourHelper  Example: include ApplicationHelper OR you can move your current_user method to application controller and you can get the access directly.

Answer (score 3):

It's is not the method `posts` is undefined. Your `current_user` object is `nil` and that means the user with this `remember_token` is not found. If you never want a `undefined method posts for nil:NilClass` type in `current_user.try(:posts)` so that if the user is logged out they won't see the error. Or create this method in your application controller.

**application_controller.rb**

```
  private
    def is_logged_in?
       current_user.present?
    end
```

And call this method in the `before_filter` section of your controller.

Anyways why not use `devise` gem for your authentication process. It's is very reliable and comes with the `current_user` and `authenticate_user!` methods defined out of the box

Answer (score 1):

It says that the value your current_user is `nil`, and nil does not have method `posts`.
Check your user's remember token, and print the parameter you feed to `find_by`.

Answer (score 0):

Eeeer... is it complaining on the view or the controller?  tell us exactly what it complains about (copy paste the result).  Maybe use @posts in your view instead of posts (ofcourse posts is undefined, @posts is defined).